# SVG filter with CSS transitions

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, css-transitions

I was doing and svg filter with css animation. I use

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
   </filter>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

and

```
filter:url('#goo');
```

for container in CSS.

Here is a fiddle
https://codepen.io/sergey_mell/pen/MoRMwR

And I got stuck into next issue. The animation appears to be carrying out like inside some box (it's size seems to be depend on initial animation state size).
Can anybody help me to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVG filters have a defined "filter region", inside which the effects are applied.  This is because some operations can be very slow (eg. gaussian blur) and you generally want to limit the area over which they are calculated.

The default filter region of a filter is:

```
x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%"
```

In other words, the element being filtered, plus a 10% border around the outside of it.  Anything outside that area will be clipped (and invisible).

The solution is to increase the filter region so that it encompasses all of your blobs.  So, for example, if we increase the margin to 50%

```
<filter id="goo" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
```

it now works properly.

```css
body{
  background:white;
  background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/d47ZIU3.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
}
.blobs{
  filter:url('#goo');
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:200px;
}

@keyframes blob-left-top-anim{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
  33%{
    transform:scale(0.9) translate(-65px,0);
  }
  62%{
    transform:scale(0.7) translate(-65px,-65px);

  }
  94%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
}

@keyframes blob-right-top-anim{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
  33%{
    transform:scale(0.9) translate(65px,0);
  }
  64%{
    transform:scale(0.7) translate(65px,-65px);
  }
  96%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
}
@keyframes blob-left-bottom-anim{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
  33%{
    transform:scale(0.9) translate(-65px,0);
  }
  66%{
    transform:scale(0.7) translate(-65px,65px);
  }
  98%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
}

@keyframes blob-right-bottom-anim{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
  33%{
    transform:scale(0.9) translate(65px,0);
  }
  68%{
    transform:scale(0.7) translate(65px,65px);
  }
  100%{
    transform:scale(1.1) translate(0,0);
  }
}
.blob{
  position:absolute;
  background:#e97b7a;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  border-radius:100%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  animation:blob-left-top-anim cubic-bezier(0.770, 0.000, 0.175, 1.000) 4s infinite;
}

  
.blob:nth-child(2){
  animation-name:blob-right-top-anim;
}
.blob:nth-child(3){
  animation-name:blob-left-bottom-anim;
}
.blob:nth-child(4){
  animation-name:blob-right-bottom-anim;
}
```

```html
<div class="blobs">
  <div class="blob">4</div>
  <div class="blob">3</div>
  <div class="blob">2</div>
  <div class="blob">1</div>
</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
   </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually made it work by setting a `width` / `height` to the `.blobs` container:

```
.blobs{
  filter:url('#goo');
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:200px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

You can probably find out the max size you need and set it to that instead of 500.

Comment: Thank for your help and quick answer!. 
I found that solution either. However, it doesn't seem ok for me because I don't know the container size so setting some extremely large values or covering whole body with container seems not ok...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not explicitly size a replaced element (img, svg etc.) then the browser gives it a default size of 300px x 150px (or something close). If you don't know the size then you need to set it via javascript if you need exact pixels, or 100%, 100% if you want it to fill its containing element.